# Problems in the ready event of the page, using indexedDb

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using indexedDB to save images offline, I'm saving the photos in base64, when the user reopens the page, the photos will be loaded automatically, the problem I'm having is, when I load the page, nothing is loaded, but I I want to be able to do this, but I do not know how to do this. thank you
the code is polluted because I tried several ways to try to make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
    var request, db;
    var vetor = [];
    if (!window.indexedDB) {
        alert("Seu navegador não suporta o recurso IndexedDB");
    }
    else {
        request = window.indexedDB.open("BD-Imagens", 4);
        request.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log("Erro ao abrir o banco de dados", event);
        }

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            console.log("Atualizando");
            db = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("imagens", { keyPath: "codigo" });
        };
        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Banco de dados aberto com sucesso");
            db = event.target.result;
            
            
        }
    
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var transaction = db.transaction(["imagens"]);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("imagens");
        var request = objectStore.get(i.toString());

        var imgtmp = new Image();
        imgtmp.src = 'data:' + request.result.nome;

        vetor.push(imgtmp.src);

        
        request.onerror = function (event) {
            alert("erro");
        };
        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            var html = "";
            html += '<div class="div-miniaturas"><img class="miniaturas" src="' + imgtmp.src + '"';
            html += '></div>';
            $('#container-miniaturas').append(html);

        };

    }
    
    vetor.forEach(function (chave) {
        var html = "";
        html += '<div class="div-miniaturas"><img class="miniaturas" src="' + valor + '"';
        html += '></div>';
        $('#container-miniaturas').append(html);
    });


});
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" class="" id="tras"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="font-size:70pt;"></span></a>
            <div class="">
                <div id="container-miniaturas">


                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="" id="frente"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="font-size:70pt;"></span></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB is asynchronous while your code is sychronous. you are using db variable before it's initialized.

So the solution for the above code will be, to keep the db variable global, put the getting Image code in a function and call the function in onsuccess event after the db has been initialized.

```
var db;
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
    var request, ==;
    var vetor = [];
    if (!window.indexedDB) {
        alert("Seu navegador não suporta o recurso IndexedDB");
    }
    else {
        request = window.indexedDB.open("BD-Imagens", 4);
        request.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log("Erro ao abrir o banco de dados", event);
        }

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            console.log("Atualizando");
            db = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("imagens", { keyPath: "codigo" });
        };
        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Banco de dados aberto com sucesso");
            db = event.target.result;
            getImgFromIdb();

        }

    }

});

function getImgFromIdb()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var transaction = db.transaction(["imagens"]);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("imagens");
        var request = objectStore.get(i.toString());

        var imgtmp = new Image();
        imgtmp.src = 'data:' + request.result.nome;

        vetor.push(imgtmp.src);


        request.onerror = function (event) {
            alert("erro");
        };
        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            var html = "";
            html += '<div class="div-miniaturas"><img class="miniaturas" src="' + imgtmp.src + '"';
            html += '></div>';
            $('#container-miniaturas').append(html);

        };

    }

    vetor.forEach(function (chave) {
        var html = "";
        html += '<div class="div-miniaturas"><img class="miniaturas" src="' + valor + '"';
        html += '></div>';
        $('#container-miniaturas').append(html);
    });

}
```

I have not tested the code but this should work.

If you are finding IndexedDB tough to use - you should use any IndexedDB library. Check out mdn doc for list of library - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: Sorry for a delay to respond, and thank you very much for the help, but now this apparent this error,
   InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Comment: Yeah vetor is not accessible inside the method, initialized in the method or globally.